# Unable to open ifstream with console input name

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have faced a strange situation. I have built a code to compare the content of multiple pairs of text files. The names of each pair of files are given from a text file called batchfile.txt in the form:
filename1.txt,filename2.txt
filename3.txt,filename4.txt
The problem is that the files do not open despite the fact that they are in the same directory as batchfile.txt which opens... I tried also with filenames as strings (I compile with C++11) but the result is the same.
The strangest thing is that it runs OK when debugging... Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <limits>


using namespace std;

void compare (ifstream &file1, ifstream &file2)   {
    string f1, f2;
    int i(0), mark(0);
    while(getline(file1, f1) && getline(file2, f2)) {
        i++;
        if (f1!=f2) {
            cout << "ERROR IN LINE " << i << endl;
            cout << "FIRST FILE: " << f1 << endl;
            cout << "SECOND FILE: " << f2 << endl;
            mark=-1;
        }
    }
    if(!mark)
        cout << "THE FILES ARE IDENTICAL" << endl << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream file1, file2, filebatch;
    string f1, f2, fb;
    string namef1, namef2;
    string bat;
    int intbat;
    size_t count(0);
    cout << "Want to compare more pairs of text files? y/n " << flush;
    cin >> bat;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << endl;
    if(bat=="y" || bat=="Y") intbat=1;
    else if(bat=="n" || bat=="N") intbat=0;
    else {
        intbat=0;
        cout << "Unknown answer. One pair is considered." << endl;
    }
    if(!intbat) {
         if(argc==1) {
         cout << "NAME OF THE FIRST FILE: " << flush;
         cin >> namef1;
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
         cout << "NAME OF THE SECOND FILE: " << flush;
         cin >> namef2;
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else{
        namef1=argv[1];
        namef2=argv[2];
    }
    file1.open(namef1.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (!file1)
    {
        // NO, abort program
        cerr << "Unable to open file1. " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    file2.open(namef2.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (!file2)
    {
        // NO, abort program
        cerr << "Unable to open file2. " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << endl;
    compare(file1, file2);
}
else{
    filebatch.open("batchfile.txt", ios::in);
    if (!filebatch)
    {
        // NO, abort program
        cerr << "Unable to open batchfile.txt " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
while(getline(filebatch, fb))  {
    count=fb.find(",", 0);
    namef1=fb.substr(0, count);
    namef2=fb.substr(count+1);
    file1.open(namef1.c_str(), ios::in); 
    file2.open(namef2.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (file1.is_open() && file2.is_open()) {  // the problem seems to be here
        cout << namef1 << " " << namef2 << endl;
        compare(file1, file2);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else    {
        // NO, abort program
        cerr << "Unable to open one of the file. " << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
file1.close();
file2.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the *exact* input you give the program when it fails? What is the actual output of the program when it fails?

Comment: On an unrelated note there's a flaw in your comparison logic: What if one file have more lines than the other? Then they aren't identical, but you will print that they are.

Comment: There are 2 ways of input. First is manually (argc=1) when I enter the filames from the console, and the second is rather automatic:  it reads the input from batchfile.txt. The program parses the string read and split it into 2 substrings which are the names of files. Each pair of files in the batchfile are separated by '\n':

Comment: Does it fail on the first or second line of batchfile.txt?

Comment: Thanks guys for paying attention. It seems that the first text files were corrupted or had some unusual properties. I removed them from the list and now it works,,,